# Matlab figure into LaTex document

Tags: matlab, latex, matlab-figure

Is it possible to export into LaTex a Matlab figure?

For now a possible way could be to export the figure into an EPS file and then include such file in the Latex document, but I was wondering if there are any packages to support .fig directly.

Thanks!

Comment: I dont think so, and it would not make sense. `.fig` is not an image file, is a MATLAB graphic class.

Comment: There shouldn't be such a possibility, without converting the `.fig` file to an image file.

Comment: Yes you are right, I haven´t thought about the fact that .fig are not image files. I think the best options are the pdf format and the eps!

Answer (score 1):

Although your problem cannot be solved (i.e. you cannot include a `.fig` file in a PDF document), you might want to use [matlab2tikz](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz), which converts the figure into a native `Tikz` figure which you can then include in your PDF file and edit as necessary.

Comment: How is it better  than what the OP says "*exporting the figure into an EPS file*" ?

Comment: @Sardar_Usama The TikZ figure will compile with the LaTeX settings and engine the document it is included in will.  Additionally, you can set the MATLAB interpreter to `'none'` for the labels and legend and then use raw LaTeX in them with using commands from packages included in the main document, such as those from `amsmath` or `siunitx` which I use all the time.

Comment: @TroyHaskin The question is about directly using *.fig* files in LaTex. Does this make LaTex to use .fig files? If yes then good to go! If no then this is an incorrect answer

Comment: I love the downvotes and the comments on this answer. The answer is NO. You can't include .fig files into a PDF. I've stated that. If you think I am mqking a mistake, please comment on this politely. The workaround I am providing gives much of the freedom .fig files have (e.g. exluding the legend) which cannot be implemented with .eps files.

Comment: This answer is not that bad. This can be useful if you need to edit your image. Although I think the most intuitive and fast way is to use eps.